# Data Binding causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular2-databinding

I'm new to Angular 4. I have a data binding field like below. But somehow, there is an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

```
<form>
<div>
  <h2>Hello {{input.value}}</h2>
  <input type="text" [value]="input.value" name="inputTest"/>
  <input type="text" #input [value]="name"/>
</div>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Below is a simple constructor:

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

I read a lot of posts about the error, I still don't understand why a simple data binding will cause the error.

I tried below code, but doesn't work.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit");
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Please help!!

Please refer the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/16atvKgf2BA6z2OjqT6h?p=preview

Comment: This post [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) should give you insights. If not, create a plunker that reproduces the problem and post it here

Comment: @Maximus I've added the plunker. I think the code is very simple, but it throws the error.

Comment: no error is thrown in the plunker you referenced

Comment: @yurzui it does work!! So it's a evaluating time issue. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) one of the operations that Angular performs is DOM update. This includes both interpolations and bindings updates. Angular performs these operations for each DOM in the order they are found in the template. These operations are explained in the [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d).

Your template looks like this:

```
  <h2>Hello {{input.value}}</h2>
  <input type="text" #input [value]="name"/>
```

So Angular starts updating DOM and first performs update for the `h2` element. It evaluates `{{input.value}}` to an empty string since it hasn't yet updated `value` binding on the `input`. So it updates `h2` to `Hello` and remembers the empty string value. Then it proceeds to updating bindings for the `input` - `[value]="name"` and sets its value to `Angular! v4.3.1`. Change detection is finished at this stage.

Then it runs the verification stage as described in the [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4). During verification stage Angular evaluates `{{input.value}}` and compares it to the previous value. Since input has already been processed the expression evaluates to `Angular! v4.3.1` which is different from the empty string that was used for the `h2` element during change detection. So you get an error:

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''.
>   Current value: 'Angular! v4.3.1'.

It also means that if you change the order of the elements in the template you will see no error. This works OK:

```
<input type="text" #input [value]="name"/>
<h2>Hello {{input.value}}</h2>
```